Public void(View v) doesn't work. Android Studio
I got the following:
public class activity_menuPrincipal extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_principal);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
        public void abrirCalculadora(View v){
            Intent openCalculadora=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(openCalculadora);
        }
    }
}

The line 25, public void abrirCalculadora(View v){ is not working, specifically "View" is always red, and I don't know why. All the errors mention "';' expected", "')' expected" and "public illegal start of expression". Yes, View is already imported.
I have had problems with my computer, but I don't think that the reason behind that.

All classes that aren't stock Java/Kotlin classes need an explicit import declaration at the top of the source file. (Either on the class directly or on the package
Hover over the View declaration that is highlighted in red. The pop-up dialog will offer you a link to "import class". Click it.
This will add an import android.view.View; statement to the top of your source file.
Repeat the same thing for the Intent class as well.


I did that already. These are my imports:
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
That's I'm going crazy haha

What happens when you "build" ?

Do you mean run it? I get the following: "
error: illegal start of expression
public void abrirCalculadora(View v){" and a little arrow under "public".

I also got the following: "C:\Users\56971.gradle\caches\transforms-4\7d0e5c76482066c1d28b18607c0dc21f\metadata.bin (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)" Maybe something got corrupted? Should I just start the project anew?

I realised I was writing where I didn't have to (inside the protected void onCreate). Here's the corrected version:
public class activity_menuPrincipal extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_principal);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
            
    }
    *public void abrirCalculadora(View v){
        Intent openCalculadora = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(openCalculadora);*
    }
}

